# TCP Sequence interpretation

Tags: nginx, networking, tcp, wireshark

How to interpret this flow diagram? What happened?

It represents the communication between NGINX Proxy server on the left and NGINX App server on the right.

There does not seem to be any relevant NGINX log record on App server. The Proxy server NGINX log recorded this:

> 21:19:17 [error] 2276#2276: *1108 upstream prematurely closed
> connection while reading response header from upstream

[image: Wireshark TCP Flow Chart]

Comment: If a TCP segment is sent to a non-existent TCP connection (that connection was closed, so it no longer exists), then the host receiving the segment should respond with a RST. That looks to be correct.

Comment: Both servers kept connection for a whole minute after the error so I don't think the reason was a non-existent TCP connection. Error appeared at 21:18 and at 21:19 both ends communicated and confirmed closing the connection.

Comment: The two lines right before that close the connection. The connection was closed, so anything sent to that connection properly results in RST.

Comment: My interpretation: 1.black - Proxy complains it didn't received something, 2.black - App server responds that it is missing something too. 1 minute pause waiting. Encrypted Alert 22 - App server says there is nothing in TLS pipe, 1.gray - App server closes connection FIN,ACK, 2.gray - so does proxy, red - App server sent the final connection reset. I see it that some packets got lost in both directions and server didn't recover. I don't know if something else can be mined from it that would help pinpoint the problem.

Comment: I fail to se a problem. The connection was properly closed, a segment was sent to a non-existent connection, and the recipient sent RST in response. All that is exactly how it works and is supposed to work. You asked for an interpretation of the TCP sequence, and TCP behaved exactly as it should. There is nothing to interpret.

Comment: NB It is a flow diagram, not a flow chart, which is something else completely.